# How to hide disable scroll but be able to use bookmarks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to disable scrolling but still be able to use the bookmark functionality. I tried overflow: hidden; but then then when I click on the bookmark link it doesn't scroll but jumps to the specific section of the page. How can I solve this?

Comment: On page load, look for the hash and implement scrolling using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use this answer from stackOverflow to solve your problem.

[stackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)